# Grails 3.3.8 unit testing service

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am trying to test a service method that uses a file under src/main/webapp/folder, however it is not working, for any reason it seems to not have access or something, the code to get the file is the following:

```
def file = grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("folder/file.txt").file
```

and the error is:

```
ServletContext resource [/folder/file.txt] cannot be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?
```

Any ideas?
it is not the grailsApplication inyection or the get resource method I think that the service do not have access to that path when it is used by the testing framework.

Comment: Are you sure that your test is a "unit-test" if you operate a grails application object and need to get access to app resources? May you post the code you're testing and the test itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidpadillaservice.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidpadillaservice/blob/master/src/main/resources/folder/file.txt

```
line number one
line number two
line number three
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidpadillaservice/blob/master/grails-app/services/davidpadillaservice/SomeResourceService.groovy

```
package davidpadillaservice

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource

class SomeResourceService {

    @Value("classpath:folder/file.txt")
    Resource fileResource

    String getFirstLine() {
        getLine(0)
    }

    String getSecondLine() {
        getLine(1)
    }

    protected String getLine(int index) {
        fileResource.file.readLines().get(index)
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/davidpadillaservice/blob/master/src/test/groovy/davidpadillaservice/SomeResourceServiceSpec.groovy

```
package davidpadillaservice

import grails.testing.services.ServiceUnitTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class SomeResourceServiceSpec extends Specification implements ServiceUnitTest<SomeResourceService>{

    void "test interacting with the service"() {
        expect:
        service.firstLine == 'line number one'
        service.secondLine == 'line number two'
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Note that this approach moves the file to `src/main/resources/` and eliminates any need to directly interact with `grailsApplication` to load the resource.

Comment: Thank you, I had to change my code a little bit, I had everything under main/webapp after move it to main/resources it works.

Comment: It can be made to work with `main/webapp/` (or just about any other directory you might like), but if you use `main/resources`, it will Just Work™.